# Does $Ran(A_+ + A_-) = Ran(A_+) + Ran(A_-)$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a symmetric matrix $A$ and its eigenvalue decomposition as $A = V \Sigma V^T$ where $V$ is the matrix whose columns are eigenvectors and $\Sigma$ is the matrix whose diagonal elements correspond to the eigenvalues. Define $\Sigma_+$ as the diagonal matrix whose elements correspond to the absolute values of the positive eigenvalues of $A$, padded with zeros. Define $\Sigma_-$ in a similar fashion using the negative eigenvalues. With this, we can define $A_\pm$ as $A_\pm = V \Sigma_\pm V^T$ and have the relation that $A = A_+ - A_-$.

Is it true that $Ran(A_+ + A_-) = Ran(A_+) + Ran(A_-)$?

I believe this is true but can't seem to show it.
Some possibly helpful facts:

$\bullet$ $x \in Ran(A_\pm) \implies x \in Ker(A_\mp)$ and therefore $Ran(A_+) \perp Ran(A_-)$

$\bullet$ $A_+A_- = A_-A_+ = 0$

Here, $Ran(A)$ is the column space/range of $A$ and $Ker(A)$ is the kernel/null space of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. In particular, every element $Ax \in \operatorname{Ran}(A)$ can be written as
$$
Ax = (A_+ x) + (-A_-x),
$$
so that $\operatorname{Ran}(A) \subseteq \operatorname{Ran}(A_+)+\operatorname{Ran}(A_-)$. Conversely, we see that
$$
\operatorname{Ran}(A) \supseteq \operatorname{Ran}(A_\pm A) = \operatorname{Ran}(\pm A_\pm^2 \mp A_\pm A_\mp) = \operatorname{Ran}(A_\pm^2) = \operatorname{Ran}(A_\pm).
$$
$\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ contains both $\operatorname{Ran}(A_+)$ and $\operatorname{Ran}(A_-)$, so it contains their sum $\operatorname{Ran}(A_+) + \operatorname{Ran}(A_-)$.

Comment: How do you prove $\mathrm{Ran}(A_{\pm}^2)=\mathrm{Ran}(A_{\pm})$?

Comment: @SungjinKim There are many approaches. Because the matrices $A_\pm$ are positive semidefinite, it suffices to note that for any matrix $M$, $M$ and $MM^T$ have the same range.

Comment: I think the following is true: For any diagonalizable matrix $A$, $\mathrm{Ran}(A)=\mathrm{Ran}(A^2)$, as the one inclusion is clear, their ranks are the same.

Comment: @SungjinKim That is indeed a valid approach. More generally, we have $\operatorname{ran}(A) = \operatorname{ran}(A^2) \iff \operatorname{ran}(A) \cap \ker(A) = \{0\}$.

Comment: @BenGrossman Thank you for your detailed reply. I just have a few questions: